# I'm trying to learn dart & I'm having issues with updating values of a 2-D list

Tags: flutter, list, dart, computer-science

```
    var PieceMap2 = {
      0: "a",
      1: "b",
      2: "c",
      3: "d",
      4: "e",
      5: "f",
      6: "g",
      7: "h"
    };
    List<List<String>> InitialBoard1 =
        List.filled(8, List.filled(8, "a", growable: false), growable: false);
    void main() {
      for (int i = 8; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
          String a = PieceMap2[j] ?? "null";
          String b = '$i';
          String c = a + b;
          print(c);
          InitialBoard1[i - 1][j] = c;
        }
        print(InitialBoard1[i - 1]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        print(InitialBoard1[i]);
      }
    }
```

This is my program. Every time I'm updating InitialBoard1 but every update of a row, seemingly, overwrites previous updates. When i print it at the end, this is the output i get.

```
a8
b8
c8
d8
e8
f8
g8
h8
[a8, b8, c8, d8, e8, f8, g8, h8]
a7
b7
c7
d7
e7
f7
g7
h7
[a7, b7, c7, d7, e7, f7, g7, h7]
a6
b6
c6
d6
e6
f6
g6
h6
[a6, b6, c6, d6, e6, f6, g6, h6]
a5
b5
c5
d5
e5
f5
g5
h5
[a5, b5, c5, d5, e5, f5, g5, h5]
a4
b4
c4
d4
e4
f4
g4
h4
[a4, b4, c4, d4, e4, f4, g4, h4]
a3
b3
c3
d3
e3
f3
g3
h3
[a3, b3, c3, d3, e3, f3, g3, h3]
a2
b2
c2
d2
e2
f2
g2
h2
[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, g2, h2]
a1
b1
c1
d1
e1
f1
g1
h1
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
```

I was expecting to get the final updated value of InitialBoard1 as:

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1]
.
.
.
[a6, b6, c6, d6, e6, f6, g6, h6]
[a7, b7, c7, d7, e7, f7, g7, h7]
[a8, b8, c8, d8, e8, f8, g8, h8]
```

Any help as to why i'm not getting the expected result would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `List.filled` it fills the list with the same value multiple times. In your case you end up with 8 references to the same array. When you print each reference at the end, they are of course the same.

Instead use `List.generate`. This will generate the list by calling the function 8 times, creating 8 *different* copies.

```
  final InitialBoard1 = List.generate(
    8,
    (_) => List.filled(8, 'a', growable: false),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to get your desired result:

```dart
Map<int, String> PieceMap2 = {
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c",
  3: "d",
  4: "e",
  5: "f",
  6: "g",
  7: "h"
};
List<List<String>> InitialBoard1 = [];
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < PieceMap2.length; i++) {
    List<String> list = [];
    for (int j = 0; j < PieceMap2.length; j++) {
      list.add("${PieceMap2[j]}${(i + 1).toString()}");
    }
    InitialBoard1.add(list);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < InitialBoard1.length; i++) {
    print(InitialBoard1[i]);
  }
}
```